# Why can't you vote to close again after you voted to retract another close vote?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, retracted-close-votes, duplicate-questions

Sometimes I closed a question as off-topic or something...,

But then I realized that it's a total duplicate, so I retract my previous vote, and then try to vote for duplicate (so basically change close vote reason), but then that doesn't work, so I am thinking to myself: How do I solve this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you searched for a duplicate to *this* question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels O man... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/how-do-i-change-a-close-vote-to-a-duplicate

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels But i can't vote fro duplicate due to another site...

Comment: [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/ability-to-retract-reopen-delete-votes)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I was ready to say that link to you :-)...

Comment: @U9-Forward put simply, you're only ever allowed one close/re-open vote on the same Q. When you retract that vote, it still counts as voted whichever way you chose.